# Code fault of falseException in thread

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, nullpointerexception, awt

I get a "falseException" while running the following code:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;


public class deneme implements ActionListener {

    private JFrame frmAsalTesti;
    private JTextField yazi;
    Sayi s1 =new Sayi();
    String sondurum="";
    JLabel sonuc;



    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    deneme window = new deneme();
                    window.frmAsalTesti.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public deneme() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frmAsalTesti = new JFrame();
        frmAsalTesti.setTitle("Asal Testi");
        frmAsalTesti.setResizable(false);
        frmAsalTesti.setBounds(100, 100, 307, 167);
        frmAsalTesti.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        frmAsalTesti.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JLabel lblDenemekIstediinizSayy = new JLabel("denemek istedi\u011Finiz say\u0131y\u0131 girin!");
        panel.add(lblDenemekIstediinizSayy);

        yazi = new JTextField();
        yazi.setText("0");
        panel.add(yazi);
        yazi.setColumns(4);

        JButton button = new JButton("Test Et");
        panel.add(button);

        JLabel sonuc = new JLabel("Sonuç");
        panel.add(sonuc);
        button.addActionListener(this);



    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        int gelen=0;
        gelen=Integer.parseInt(yazi.getText());
        System.out.println(s1.Asalmi(gelen));
        if(s1.Asalmi(gelen))
        {
            sondurum="girilen sayı asaldır";
        }
        else
        {
            sondurum="girilen sayı asal değildir";
        }

            sonuc.setText(""+sondurum);

    }



}
```

The error, linked to the line: `sonuc.setText(""+sondurum);`, is:

```
     falseException in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" 
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at deneme.actionPerformed(deneme.java:94)
```

I couldn't find the solution and I am waiting for your answers. I just want to change the label so it will be a dynamic label.

Comment: Consider adding the java tag if you want java people to help

Comment: Which line is deneme.java: 94? kindly mention it in your question or comment that line.If possible put the complete stacktrace using e.printStackTrace();

Answer (score 3):

You get a NullPointerException at the line

```
sonuc.setText(""+sondurum);
```

What could possibly be null at this line and cause such an exception? Answer: `sonuc`.

So, is `sonuc` initialized somewhere?

The only place where `sonuc` is referenced in the code is in the `initialize()` method:

```
JLabel sonuc = new JLabel("Sonuç");
```

And this creates a **local** variable with the same name as the field `sonuc`. So the field `sonuc` is never initialized.

Replace the above line by

```
this.sonuc = new JLabel("Sonuç");
```